# How to add images to Watson Conversation response?

Tags: java, watson-conversation

[image]I'm a newbie to Java and Watson Conversation. Is this possible to add images to Watson Conversation response? I want to add an image to Watson Conversation I made a Chatbot on Watson Conversation and integrated it with Facebook as Java web application.I want to add images in Watson response.

```
public class TestConversation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        MessageResponse response = null;
        Map context = new HashMap();

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String userName = br.readLine();
            // Add userName to context to be used by Conversation.
            context.put("userName", userName);

            while (true) {
                String input = br.readLine();
                response = conversationAPI(input, context);
                System.out.println("Watson Response: " + response.getText().get(0));
                context = response.getContext();
                System.out.println("———–");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static MessageResponse conversationAPI(String input, Map context) {
        ConversationService service = new ConversationService(ConversationService.VERSION_DATE_2016_07_11);

        // Credentials of Workspace of Conversation
        service.setUsernameAndPassword("******************", "****************");
        MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(input).context(context).build();

        // Workspace ID of Conversation current workspace
        String workspaceId = "******************";
        MessageResponse response = service.message(workspaceId, newMessage).execute();
        return response;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a different issue to what your initial question was.

Comment: The issue was the same but I think, I couldn't explain it well my bad. Let me explain it, I made a chatbot on Watson Conversation and created a java web application to call API's and calling Conversation workspace in- java app (as you can see in the code above) and to integrate it with the Facebook messenger. Now I want Watson to give image response to Facebook Messenger. How can it be done? Please give the proper solution as I mentioned before I'm a newbie to java and Watson Conversation.

Comment: Java SDK is not my strong point but the only thing that stands out is you are resetting your conversation every time in `conversationAPI()` method. Once you have connected a conversation, you need to pass back the same context and not create a new conversation object/session each time. Try looking at the example: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/develop/conversation

Comment: Kindly can you correct my code for the problem you point out? I would really appreciate it

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty Could you be more specific, where exactly am I am resetting conversation in ConversationAPI () method? Point out the line please

Answer (score 0):

Watson conversation is just text that is sent back. So it is up to your application to render the image.

If you use the [conversation simple application](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple), you can use HTML to render. For example, set the output text to the following value.

```
Here is a picture of a tiger:<br><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Tiger.25.jpg">
```

[image]

When you display that text in conversation simple it will show the following:

[image]

---

Another option is you can store the image within conversation by saving as [base64 format](https://www.base64-image.de). However you have a limit of 10MB on a conversation file, so it's unlikely to be useful except for small icons.

Example:

```
Smile: <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPAAAADwCAYAAAA+VemSAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAgAElEQVR4nO3deXxU5b0/8M/3nJlsk52EbBNkR4ggq1ogIK64oai4tlqtS6tW21qq16tW6a+KXmzdqt57UYt1u1ZURGkVNZAEhAquBQXZJAtJSCDrzGTmnPP9/RGWAElmJpmZM2fyfb9evoTMmTPfDPOZ5znPec55ACGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQoQcmV2A8I/XOjPh03M0UgcSGfkEJRvgFMPgFAJlgJAKIAVAPACAoBJT6hH7IG4GQz/w13aAmsHcwuD9ikItALUwG3UMZY+N9TrY1VqaWrkvsr+pCJYEOArwG1CRnz9c15UigjGUiYYCPJRBQwgYDCDOpNLaGfiBwDvAtIOAHazQDhW8CXuqttNlh74QhEkkwBHGH+Q4tET7ZAXGSQycSKAxDIzBwdbTOjwEfMvAJmL+yoD6L5vHu5HOrm0zu7D+RAIcZlxemK8bfBqYi4lwCgNFAFSz6woTjYBNTFgHg8pUUj+hGT/sMbuoWCYBDjEuyU7WlfizQHwGA6cRMMrsmszEwLfEKIFCH6ku34fSQoeWBDgEeK2zwND4AmbMAWEWgASza4pSHgCfEONdRVWW0/SKarMLsjoJcC9x2aAMHfoFYMwDcA5it1scLgaAT4np74rN9xpNq60zuyArkgAHgTdMsuuu2jkAXw/gLAA2s2uKET4AH4DoBVWrXE6zoJldkFVIgAPAZYOGaqzfQODrAMo1u54Yt4cZL9igPU8za3eaXUy0kwD3wFuWN0lh5Q4AV0G6yJFmAFjBxE/Yi6s/MruYaCUBPgozFL204FIQfgtgitn1CACMdSBapBZXvk0Ew+xyookE+ABmkF6efz4ZtIAJ482uRxyLwJuY6FF1T9UrMgusgwQYgFbmnEvgBcw4wexahH8EfM3g+20zqpeZXYvZ+nWAveWFkxXDWARgptm1iF5grGPwnfaZ1WvNLsUs/TLAvNZZoGv4L4CvQD99D2IIA3hFVZS7+uPEkH714eUS2AzFeSsTFgCc6v8ZwkLaiOgPyp7KRf3p+LjfBNi7qnCKSsb/yABVbCPgc52Mm+KK92w0u5ZIiPkA84ZJdsNd+xtm/gMAu9n1iIjQmPkxW1vS7+ncbe1mFxNOMR1g7+r8CSrREgbGml2LiDwCvtIJ18YVV31ldi3hophdQDgwg/TVzjsUonUS3v6LgRMVxnp9tfMO5thsrGLul+KVQ9P0+PbFAC41uxYRVd5VvbiezqhqMLuQUIqpAHtXFU5RFGMpgEKzaxFRabehKJfETa/YYHYhoRIzXWit1PljRTFWQ8IrujdIMYxyrSz/erMLCRXLt8BcAptucz4O5lvNrkVYBxOesO2putPq54wtHWAuyU7W1bjXAZxndi3CiuhDNc41j07Z12x2Jb1l2QBz6XF5BrT3GJhodi3Cugj4WtFxHs2qqjS7lt6wZIB5tXOETvwx5HhXhMYuldTTqXj3DrMLCZblBrG4PH+UDi6BhFeEzmCdtTVcmjvG7EKCZakAc0n+8bpBn4BQYHYtItZQrs7qJ+3lg4rMriQYlulCc2nuGB3Kx3JTORFmdTrTGfEzK78xu5BAWKIF9q4pGK9DXS3hFREwUCVe7S0vnGx2IYGI+hb4wJ0hVwLIMLsW0a80GITTo/1CiKgOMK/OGaLD9ikIOWbXIvqlPaquT6VZNbvMLqQ7UduF5o8KBmhk+4eEV5goT1PVFbzWmWl2Id2JygDzWmeiHodl/X1lP2E+AkbrOt7hksFRuWBd1AWYGYqu88sAppldixAAAOZiXfW9xBx9eYm6grTS/D+DcbHZdQhxlHlaecGjZhdxtKgaxNLLnLcz8xNm1yFEdwj4hTqj6jmz6zgoagLsLXOerDCXAogzuxYheuBjAzPtp1Z9anYhQJQEmNc6M3WNNwIYbHYtQgRgt+rFxGi4PY/px8DMUHTNeAUSXmEdg/Q4LImGQS3TCzDK8u8FaLbZdQgRpPOMsoK7zC7C1C60b1XBLFKwErJ4trAmg4nPNnMBctMCzGtyBuq67RsAA82qQYi+4xpVx1iaVV1vxqub1oXWddtfIOEVlke5ukpPmfXqpgRYW51/OeTG6yJ2XKGVFpjyeY54F5pL8rN0lTZBWl8RW+pVVSuiabV1kXzRiLfAukrPQsIrYk+WrtsiPoswogHWSvOvgHSdRey6Qit1XhLJF4xYF5pLc7N1qJsBZEXqNYWIOEataqcxNLVyXyReLmItsA7lIUh4Rawj5Og6FkTu5SLAuzp/gkL0GWTChugfdIMwKRL30wp7C8wMUgiPQ8Ir+g9VYTwdiUXFwx5gvdR5FUAzwv06QkSZ6XpZQdgHtML6DcEb8pN0F30LYFA4X0eIKFWhurXRdHZtW7heIKwtsOai/4SEV/RfhUaS+ttwvkDYWmBe6yzQNd4GICrv5idEhLhU3T6MZu2qCcfOw9YC6z6+BxJeIZI01Re264bD0gJzef4g3aCtAOLDsX+zMAO1jSp21ylobFPQ6ia4vYQ4GyMhDkhOMJCXaaAwW4cjgc0uN2oYTKhuIFTW29DURmjzEFzthIQ4RoKdkZwIFAzQUZitIyEuJt83j6pjRDgWEbeFeocAoBu4DzEQXmbgqx12rN9ix4bv7di82waPN7DvvLxMHROGaZg43IsZJ/gwINUIc7XRQzcIn221Y/13NnyxIw7fVdjg0wJ7bmGWjvHDfJg8wofiE7xIc8REoBN0Bf8B4NZQ7zjkLTCX5A7WVXULLHx3yZr9Kv5eloB/bohHzf6+H2UoxJg80oe5U9tx+ngvVCUmPpTH2FFjwxul8Vj5eTwa2/r+vtlU4JTjvbh4mgfFRV4opt8Aqk98KmujaGbtzlDuNOQB1lYXLAHhmlDvNxIq9ip47n0HVn4RB90Iz/heXqaOn57pxtyp7TET5G932/DsCgfWbraDw/QrDcrWccNsF86Z3G7hIPNi24zqG0O5x5B+SrmsYKTO2AyLzbpq9wHPvZ+E11YnBdzV66shOTruuaIFE4dH6AXDoNlFeGypAys2JMCI0BHCKKeG+65sxehBlnzffKqqjKZpFdtDtcOQBlgrzf9fgG4I5T7DbUeNDf+5JBlbK8MyHNAjIuCKmR7ccWEr7JF/+T75Zpcd9y5JQWV95JtDVWHcMNuNG2a7oZDFejGMZ2wzq0J2LByyAB+4Sd0uAImh2me4vbYqAU+9m4x2n7l1jB6k4eHrWlCYpZtbSAAMJjyzPAlLPk6MWKvbnYnDNfzx2mYMTLfUAKFL1fm4UN0EL2Rfn5pmvwUWCS8z8MQ7Dixaan54gY5jyGsXpePfu6K7GfZpwD0vJuPFleaHFwA+32bDdX9Kw65aSx2xJRk2ujlUOwtJC8wrhsfrDvcPVliMWzcIf3zdgWWfRt8ck6R4xqIbW3DyKK/ZpRzD7SXMX5yKT7+1m13KMdIcjCdubsLYIZY5Lq5TdftxNGuXp687CkkLbKR4rrVCeJmBBa9EZ3gBwNVO+PV/p+CbXdEVEk0H7vyflKgMLwA0tRFufSYV26ot0xIP1G3eK0Oxoz63wMwgraxgEwGjQ1FQOD37XhIWf5DU6+enORjjhvgwulCDM0tHZooBmwowE9xeYM8+BduqbfjXFjuqGnr/YcpINvDibxpRmB0F/VQAC15N7tOXXkaygXFDfDi+UD/wvjFUhcFMaPUA1Q0qdtSo+HqHHTv70B3Oy9Tx1zubkGWBSTNE+LcyvWocEfo0CtfnAGvlznNg8Iq+7ifcPvkqDvMXpwb9PEUBTjvRi0umuTF5pBbwqOcPdSpWfR2P11cnoK4x+I7OsDwdf5vfiHi7uaOsfy9LxMI3HEE/T1UYZ07w4pLpHowf6gv43G1FvYr318fjjbJENLUF//E8cagP/3tHsyXOsTPz2faZ1R/2ZR99D3Cp8x2AL+zrfsKprlHB5Q9noNkV+K9LBJwzuR3Xn+3CkJzejw77NOD9zxLw3PtJ2NsUXJAvn+HG7+aF7VJSv3bWqrj6kXS0+4J73y48xYPrznLBmdX7lrDNQ3izPBHPf5CANk9w79tN57hw87muXr92BC21zajq011a+xRgLhmcq6u+3QCi8+DogAdfSca76wLvAmanGbj/qhZMHRO6IepmF+G/3kzGis8CnyKuKMDrd+/HsDxzTi/d8VwqyjcFPiM2L1PH769uxZSRoXvfavareODlZHy2NfCPmN0GLH9gH7LTor4rram6vbAvlxr2aRDLUH3XI8rD2+4j/HND4OEdN8SH1/9jf0jDCwCpSYw/XNOCe69sDbh7ZxjA8iC+eEJpb5OCNZsDD++kET68dndjSMMLALkZOp69rQnXnB54i+rTgE++ssS1NDZD9f6kLzvodYCZQQxc15cXj4TqfQq8AZ5dmFbkw3O/bEZ6GK+AmTvVgz/d1BLwzKtddeaMrFbsVQOe1zzrRC+evqUJKYnhed+IgDsucuHXcwM/nKjca40J0wbohr7c/K7Xv6VWnn86gOG9fX6kBPqhKjpOw6PXN0dk0Gh6kRcLftICCuCfLVyh8CfNEVj3c9IIHx76aTPiIjAH5cenufGzs90BbZuSFP2DWABAwEitzNnrmz72OsAECulVFeGSlWpgpLPnJtiRYGDh9S0RvZj8rIntuOpU/x/GaWPMmdQxJEdHfmbPx94ZyUbEwnvQz89tw6QR/rvppxwfBVPsAkTgXl8/0KsA81pnJhhRPfLc2a8vcvV4+ufuy9r8fljD4Zdz2nq8qmbsEA1nTTInwIoC/GpuW7e9BIUYD/64BVmpkW3pFAX447UtPZ7rnTnWi3FDrBNgAJfyyqFpvXlirwKsa7gEFrrjxkmjvHjoulY4Eo78R0+IY9x9WRvOndJuSl12G/DEzc1dXlI4aYQPf76p2dSrbU4f78UDV7cc043PSu2Y8jmtyJyQZKcZeO72ZowoOPZLd8ZYL/5wTYsJVfVJgh7XflFvntirg2ettOBjAKf15rlmavMoWLPZjvpmQnYa40ejvUiOgntXMQNfbLfjm112KAqjaJAvqq4TbvUQ1n1rR7NLQU6GgckjvIiPgnMPzMCXO+zYVm0DEWPcYM3v4VL04n/aZlSfE+yzgg7wgXO/lbDYRftCRDlNVbWCYBcID7oLbdi0yyDhFSLUbIZuuzjYJwUdYGa+ItjnCCH8YyDobAXVhT5wv+ddwT5PCBEQQ7XRIJpaWRXoE4JqgQ2d5kHCK0S4KIaOoFY0DCrATDwnuHqEEMFg5guC2T7g1pTXOjN1jWsRptUchBAAAJ+q2wfSrF2NgWwccAus63weJLxChJtdt/nODHTjwLvQjKCadiFELwWRtYACzBsm2QGc1euChBDBOI9LAuvtBhRgrW3PLAC9mmwthAhapkZ5Pwpkw8C60ESz+1SOECI4ihLQvOiAAqwAp/etGiFEMCjAzPk9jXRgzaOaQLYVQoSMrpKaTcW79/e0kd8WWNfV0yDhFSLSVJ21mf42CqQLLd1nIUyh+M1eAAH2vxMhROgx8Rn+tukxwLw6ZwjAQ0JXkhAiUMQ4nksKnD1t02OAddh6fbtLIUTf6TYu7unxnrvQxNNCWo0QIjisTO3p4R6naxEw1fxbvvWsqkHFrhoFaQ6GM1sP66oKIna0eQhV9Sr2NhEGpjNGFETnzfAI3GOAuz09xCWD03XV14AQLQIeak1thAdfScHqb45cvyclsSPIhVk68jJ1DEw3kJdpIDfDQE6GgfQAVxwQ1tbmIdTuV7Bnn4LaRrXjz/tVVOxVUFWvoqHlyI/18YUa/t+1LX1aiTJMdFVpz6Dp9V3eK7fbAGurneeC+P3w1dV7hgHc9GQavtge/L1N4+1AZoqOrFQDmSkGBqYzMpINZKUZyEo1kO5gpDoYqYkG0pPZEuvM9gfMQJOL0NSmoLmN0ORSsL9VQV2jgn0tCuqbCfXNCvY1K9jbpMDtDX7qQk66gdfu3o+0KOvFMXCGfUbVx1091m0XmsFTo3X2xprNcb0KLwC0+4A9+1Ts2RfYjTUdCYdDne5gpDkMpCQyHAkMR4KBpHhGUjyQFM9ITWIkxhlIjGckxgMpiQYcCej3XwLMQIub4GonuL0K3O1Aq1tBqwdweTp+1ubp+JnbS2h2EZoOhLS57fCfw622UcEbZYm4cXZ0rS2sAFMBBBdgIgR0NYQZvtwRubuKt3k6PlxVDb3fR7wdiLczbGpH2ImA5MSOrrwjnqEojMQ4ht0GxNk6VoxQFcDR6abzCuGYlSUOirMDCd0sypYYz1Coo0vZFa8GeLpprdztBM04/JjHS/BqgNcHeHwEwyC0ejoea3F3BMzlIegGweMFvBrBp6FXraFZvorgZytQzN1nscsAM4P0MkwMX0l9E8lFyEKh3YcDq9wT9h06konKoYV+L94ehWMkhCndPdT1p2iVcxiA9HDV01fD86JzxFBY38gu1luKAlm8Or+wqwe6DLCuGJPCW0/fROuQv7C+aP1s6dR1j7jLADMwIbzl9E3BAAMDUqKwqyMsb+zg6AwwQwk8wKRQ1B7/Ah2DQIEs8ixEMIbmashOi86GgcBdZrLrUWiO7hYYAKaM9OHDz3teovjqq6/GSSedhNraWtTV1R36f11dHWpqauB2uyNUrYiE+Ph45OTkIDs7G7m5ucjKykJOTg5ycnJQV1eHRx55pMfnTxkZzY0CT+7qp8cEmEsKnDqQFf6C+mZ6kRdEHecYu/P9999j/vz53T7e1taG2tpaVFRU4I477uh2u7S0NCiKgqamJhhGdH5DxxoiQlpaGtxuN9rbu16AfcCAAVi4cCEyMjKQlZWF9PTux139hRcAZoyN5gBTLq/JGXj08qPHBFiz0QnUUyqixMB0A0XHafj3ru6nc2/YsAENDQ0YMGBAl487HA4MHToUmZmZPb7WnDlzcOeddwIAmpub0djYiKamJrhcLjQ3N8Pj8cDlcsHlcqGlpQUulwtut/vQzzRNQ0tLC+rr61FXF9Tyr5aVm5uLzMxMpKSkQFEUJCcnIyEhAUlJSUhKSkJKSgqSkpKQmJiIpKQkpKamIjExEWlpaYf+IyJcd911+OKLL7p8jaSkJEyZ0u0ZlkM0TcMHH3zQ4zYpiYzJI7y9+l0jRTPsYwD0HGDF4CK2yHn3U8e19xhgwzDw3nvv4dprrw3Za6ampiI1NbVXz/3rX/+Kxx9/vNvHlyxZgsLCQrhcHTOBmBktLYenwHb+c2dutxs+3+HW46677uq2p3DcccfhtttuO/R3VVXhcDi63DYlJeXQnx0OB1S1Y/ZaQkICPv74Yzz88MPd/i4333wz5s6d2+3jkVRSUoJ9+/b1uM30Ii9sUb7qtWIYRQBWdf7ZsV1oQlGkCuqrMye04y/LHT12o99++21cc801IIr+b6Xk5GRkZmb67RH4c9ddd3X7WFpaGs48M+CVO7qVmJjY531EyhtvvOF3m7Mmdt1NjyZMdEw2uxqFtkyAnVkGJg3v+bhl165d2LhxY4QqEtFm+/bt2LBhQ4/bZKcZmFYUzce/B3HPAWYGARgdsXpC4MIfefxus2TJkghUIqLR888/D/YzpjPnlHaLXHDirwVek18IIOXojaLZ6eO9SEns+c0vLy/H1q1bI1SRiBaVlZV+B6+IgAtO8d8IRIkB/NHAnM4/OCLAGmNkZOvpu3g74/yTez5+YWa89NJLEapIRIsXXngBut7z3OZTjvehMCsq5z93SUuwjej89yMCrDANj2w5ofHj01yw+1nLbcWKFdiyZUtkChKm27lzJ5YtW+Z3u+vOjK5rf/0h48iMHhFgAzQssuWERm6GgbMn9dwKG4aBp556KkIVCbM99thjflvfouM0y03JZUb3ASbAki0wAFx7hhuKn0tsy8vL8dlnn0WmIGGa9evXo7y83O92PzvbelNpSUH3XWgitmyAh+ZqmHGC/3N5CxcuPGLSg4gt7e3teOihh/xuNzRPD+jzEm2ouxaYGcSMoZEvKXRum+P2O5tm+/btePHFFyNTkIi4Z599Fj/88IPf7W6f0wYLzO05BqO7Y+C1OdkAkiJdUCgNydFwyTT/3aLFixdj586dEahIRNKWLVvw8ssv+93upFE+FJ8Q3fOeu8epXDL40FUbhwLs09QCcwoKrZvOdfm9LajX68Xvf/97aFp0Xrwtgud2u3HPPff4/TdVFcb8S1ojVFV4eO3GoaweCrCioMdFlKwi3cG4cXab3+2+/vprGZWOIQ899BC2b9/ud7tLp3swNM865327oujasQEmpphogQFgXrEHQ3L8t64vvfQSSktLI1CRCKe3334by5cv97tdmoNx07nWOu/bFerU2B4KsEGImQDbVOD+q9v8nlZiZtx3332oqamJTGEi5L777jssXLgwoG1/e0lrTKyd1bmx7dQCx0YX+qBxQ3y46lT/A1pNTU343e9+F4GKRKhpmobbbrut2zt2dFZ8ghfnTrHeaaOucKfG9nAbFUMt8EG3nO/C0Fz/Xendu3dHoBoRavX19aivr/e7XUaygXuvtPbA1RG4iy40x1gLDHRc6PDI9S2I72bZEWFtgUzIIQLuv6oVWamxcy8z4i5aYELsDGJ1NjRPx28u9j8qLWLTj2e5MWOsVc/5do3pqBaYy7NSAO7djZ4s4NLpHsydaplrPkWITBjmw60XxOSX9wAuGZwAHGyBdXvMdZ+PdvdlrZgwTOZA9xf5mToW3dji9zJTiyLYjHzgQIA1Rc3peXvrs6nAwutbkJ9p7ZP4wr/UJMYTP29GuiN2jnuPphlaLnAgwGSgb7dBtIisVAPP/LI56HWV9u7dG6aKhD9NTU1BbR9vZ/zppmbLz7byh4gygEODWEaGmcVEUmGWjj/f3Iyk+MBHpleuXIl33nknjFWJoxmGgSeffBI7duwI+Dmqwnj4uv5yqNQpwET9owU+qOg4DU/8vCngEOu6jgceeAALFixAW1tMDopEldraWvziF7/ACy+8EPBzVIXxx5+2YubY2Jis4c/BzCoAYBxIc38ycbiGp29phiMh8Jb4rbfewkUXXYRVq1aFr7B+jJmxfPlyXHbZZVi/fn3Az1OIseCaVpw5oX+Et4PRqQUG+l2AAeDEoT785dZmpCUFfky8d+9e/OpXv8J9990X9PGZ6F5FRQVuvPHGoN/XeDtj0Y2tmO3nnmixxsARx8D9M8AAMHawD8//pino0enly5fj4osvxrvvvisrFvaB2+3G4sWLMW/ePL8rKBwtKd7Ac79s7jfd5s7IQOcA978udGdDcnS8eGcjRg8K7gL/hoYG3H///bjkkkuwcuVKvysAiMO8Xi9effVVnH/++Xj66afh8QQ30aZggIGX5jdh3JD+MGDVpU4BZqNfDWJ1JSuV8cKvGzF3avDf5jt37sT8+fMxb948rFy5MgzVxQ7DMLBy5UpcfPHFePTRR9HQ0BD0PqYV+fC3+fsxJCe2TxX16MAgVsc8FerfLfBBcTbg3itbMMqp4bG3HPAFecedbdu2Yf78+RgzZgzmzZuHc845BwkJCeEp1mIaGxuxbNkyvPnmm6ioqOjVPoiAG2e7cONsl99rvWMdH+g1H5xoZqn1kMJtXrEbE4Z5ce9Lqfi+KvhFYzdv3owHH3wQixYtwuzZs3H55Zdj5EjLrVoTEps3b8bSpUvx/vvvB91N7iwrlXH/1S2YNia2LkzoLTpw7cLBAFv6bpThMDxfx5I7G/HkMgf+rzShxzWIu9PW1oalS5di6dKlmDhxYp/X/bWSdevW4bXXXgvJonJnT2rH3Ze1IjVJxhg6SQQOB1j6eV2ItzPmX9qKU8e1Y+EbydhV2/sl3D///PMQVhb9/K0KGIiB6QbuvLgVZ0yQVrcLiQCg8KaiOBwOsujClJE+vH73ftxyviusNwewyr25mDms88NVhXH1LDfe/M/9Et7uJTCDiFcOTdPj2xvNrsYqqhpUPPNeEj78PB7hOP07YMAAjBkzBqNGjcLIkSMxYsQIOJ1O2O32gPcxceLEbs9Njxs3LqilVn0+HyorK7F161Zs2bIFW7ZswaZNm9DYGJ6PzNQxPtw+pxUjCvrxCHOA1NbEBOKSwbm66ttjdjFWs7XShqeXJ2HN5riwv5aiKMjLy4PT6YTT6UR2djays7ORlZWFAQMGIDU1FQ6HA8nJyYiPjw8owF6vF62trWhra0NzczMaGhpQX1+Puro67N27F5WVlaisrMSePXsiMlFl7GAfbr/QhYnD++153aCpuj2DeHXOEJ1sgV/yIY7w5XY7lnyciPJNcWFpkYOlqmqPy2qqqgpFUaJmgbeJwzVcc7rLwkudmEeFLZ+4NHeMDnWT2cVYXcVeBf9XmoS318bD47XgqlkRpCjAtDFe/OxsN8YOjo4vEitSSR1G3tL8iQpoo9nFxIrGNgUrPovHsk8TsK2696PWsciZZeD8kz244GQPcjOioLticbqinkDeVYVTFMX4l9nFxKJvd9uwbF08Pv4yHvta+ufUoeQExsxxXlx4igcTh/ssuaRntNKZxpG3zHmywrzO7GJimWEAWyptKNsUhw83xmNnH84nW0FGsoGpY3w4Y3w7ThntRZycpAwLQ8UE8q3On0pEa8wupj/ZUWPDZ1vt+HybHRu/t2F/q7VbZ0eCgQnDNEwa4cOUET4cX6hJSxsBBngS+crzp5NBZWYX018xAztrVHy+3Y4tlTZ8V2HD9j0q2n3RmQCbCgzJ1TCqQMOoQh3jh/pwfKEOhWSaY6QZhnKSDbqqgGRAwSxEHatHdL6Lom4QfqhVsLXKhop6FdUNCioP/L+uSY3I6aqsVAP5A3Q4swwUDNDhzDYwPE/DsDwtVu+1bD02Q7WBNQZZuwsXa1SFjwn1QT4NaGhR0dhK2N9KaHIpaGwlNLUp8GqEVjfBYEA3gDbPka14gp0Rd2BCV0qiAbsKpCUz0pIMpCcz0h0G0hwGstNY1pOyCBvblet3zoUAAAYWSURBVBaSWWuWYbcBuRk6cuUK7n7P7uNGxQ5jv9mFCCF6QbU3KfDuqQIgK38JYS2tKP6hVqFZ0MD8b7OrEUIE5UsiGB2jV4RPTS5GCBEEBq0DDq4PzCQL/whhJQa/BRwIsM2oKgUgS/AJYQWMKtvMqvXAwaVVZkFjwn+bW5UQIhBEeIYIBnB4aRXYFO0pyGi0ENHOpXgPN7aHAkzTauuY8BdzahJCBIIJf6Izqg4tZ3HEHEobtT8IQO6PJUR0qrS5tIWdf3BEgGl6fQuYfhvZmoQQASG6nc6uPWKF+WOuYrDNrHwV4FciV5UQwj9ebCuufPvon3Z5GZIa57mFge/DX5QQwh8GvlV136+7eqzLANMp+5ptqnIO5NywEGZrsOk0h2btbe3qwW4vBKZpFduZ6DIA/W/5cyGig5uZ59Csym3dbdDjlfz24spVTHQR5PywEJHmBTDPPrN6bU8bBXTjJa0s/wIwvQkg/OuICCE8TDTXXlz5T38bBnQvHVtx9XI2MBuALIImRHjtZ9DsQMILBNgCH9RePqhINfQVAAb1qjQhRA9op6ob59Ks6u8CfUZQd7OLn757kwp9MoCPgq5NCNGTVarX+6NgwgsEGWAAoBk1e9WaqtnM9CAAuR+tEH3DzPyIWlN1Bp1RVxvsk/t093Df6vyzCPQCCAV92Y8Q/RPXAHSDbUbV+73dQ59uCG2fWf2hathPAPByX/YjRD/0d9WmFPUlvEAfW+DODpxqehoywCVE9xhVIPzKNqPqzVDsLmRLMtiKq5erSvsJDDwOQAvVfoWIERqDFqkebVSowguEsAXujEvyj9dVWgBgXjj2L4TFfKQz/SZ+ZuU3od5xWJfA863KP1MhepQJ48P5OkJEIwJtNAyebz+1qiR8rxFmzCC9PP98YnqAgYnhfj0hzEaEfzOwQJ1e9SYRwrpKXMQWoWWGopcWXEqEuxmYEKnXFSJimDeAlIVqceVb4Q7uQaasIu0ty5uksHIHgCsByGqzwsoMACuY+Al7cXXEZyiaugw8r84ZokG9mYhuAiALZgoraWHmF22G8WeaVbPLrCJMDfBBXJ6VYugJ1zPxLwEMM7seIXqwjUBPKornrzS9vsXsYqIiwJ15y/ImkUHXENFVALLMrkcIAE0A3mXil2zTqz+O1PFtIKIuwAfxiuHxeorrLDD9BMCFkJsJiMjyAvgQhL+rifwmTa52mV1QV6I2wJ1xyeB03eabA8ZPAJwOi9QtrIdAG8H4m0LaqzSjJupv6mi5IPCanIG6YZsNxvkAZgNIMbsmYWluAGuI6T0Fxls0s7rC7IKCYbkAd8ZrnYmabkyDgQuIaC6AQrNrEhbAqAXhQxCWq5r3H93dstUKLB3go3nXFIxXDZzHjHMATIEcN4sOXgCfEeEfuoL346ZVfWl2QaESUwHujNc6EzXDmKSwMo2ZpwMoBpBmdl0iIlwAvmDmcij4yKYqa2hqpdvsosIhZgN8NH4Dqi8vb7xqqNOZeBqA0wAMMLsuERItANYz0xooRrmtJamMzt3WLxYk6DcBPhozFJTlHq+zbQITxhN4AjoutpAZYdFtH4AvGPQFMb5QoX+BGXu2HFyxvr/ptwHuDpcX5uusT2JDmUTEYxhURODRkPfKDHsAbGLmzaTQRp3UjXHTdm+OpokUZpMPZQC4JD9LUzGKQCMYGEHACGKMYMJwAMlm12dxrcTYxoTvGfiegO+ZeavNwFaaVV1vdnHRTgLcR1xemK8ZPIKAjnATD4eBfACFIORArrbygVEHoAIKqplpG6EjrDaFvqfpFdVmF2hlEuAw6jjOPi7HB1+eQpRPBgoMUB6RUQBQHgFO7hhIS4P1JqS0AGgioIGBSoD3MCtVioJqBlcbzNV2Pa4ap+6qlS5v+EiAowS/ARVOZxp0Jd3HWjoZlEYqpYM5jZjSQEaaAUonhgMAQLDjcPedAKR32l0qgdQj9g/WATR3+lEjcChYrWD4AIAJrQq4Caw0MXETwI1sUBMr3GQnWyNUoxE/qmzsr4NGQgghhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBBCCCGEEEIIIYQQQgghhBBCCCGE6Af+P+HhSrt5F5C5AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Simon, I tried both mentioned ways but none of them worked for me. I tried it in Watson Conversation, in eclipse and in Facebook Messenger as well but in eclipse, I encountered an error "  java.lang.NullPointerException " and in Messenger no response at all. The code and error screenshot is attached.Please have a look and let me know where did I commit the mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Screenshot of error and code are attached. Have a look

Comment: In Watson conversion it shows the text only, no picture.

Comment: It won't render images in the Watson try it out. You need to create an application that can render the HTML. But you have a different issue, as the image text should have no impact.

Comment: How can it be done? Would you mind to give example and code snippet?